# Javascript - How to Get Image Url from Right Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing an app which allows users to work with images online. Everything works so far but on some sites - they are not using the img Tag. So I need alternative methods of getting the image url when right clicked on.

In FHM.COM they have this:

```
<div class="efImage" style="background-image: url('https://igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t51.2885-15/e15/924583_1497100237194525_212104957_n.jpg');">        
</div>
```

How would I get that image's url when right clicked on?

Comment: What do you mean "when right clicked on"?  Are you asking how to see this image style in developer tools initiated by a right-click?

Comment: @jfriend00 how does this confuse you? So I need alternative methods to get the image url when right clicked on.

No mention of Developer tools

Comment: Really pisses me off when I get voted down because someone decided to "edit" re-write my question!

Comment: You didn't get downvoted because of an edit.  You got downvoted because your question was not entirely clear to some and you did not respond to a comment asking for clarification.  StackOverflow works a lot better if you don't post a question and then disappear until the next day.

Comment: It can take days to get an answer - some of us have work to do that requires us not to sit looking at SO. The question was clear to all but you! So that was a pitiful reason to downvote.

But that's ok - I will flag your downvote as unreasonable.

Comment: I didn't ask you to sit there looking at SO.  I asked you to check in a few times after you asked your question and see if there were comments asking for clarification and, if so, to respond to them in a timely manner.  That's how ***everyone*** gets the most out of SO and is the community-friendly thing to do.  If you're going to be non-responsive to clarifying questions, then be prepared to get downvotes.  It's that simple.  You make it sound like a downvote is the end of the world.  It's not.  It's one person's opinion of how clear or useful your question is.  Ignore it and get over it.

Comment: Sorry I probably was in bed... When you eventually posted. Noone said being voted down was the end of the world. You make it sound like being flagged is though. Everyone get's different things out of SO in different ways - you are totally arrogant to assume how everyone benefits from SO.

Comment: The SO community works best if you aren't non-responsive to clarifying questions for long periods of time.  You can choose not to use SO that way if you want, but it is not the best way to do things for the benefit of all and will not get you the most attention for getting an answer.  In fact, some questions will actually get closed in a few hours if non-responsive to clarifying questions.  Stack Overflow is more "interactive" than other more traditional online forums.  The majority of eyeballs are going to see your question in the first 30 minutes after posting.

Comment: I recommend that people who don't want downvotes or close votes and who want to maximize their odds of getting a good answer and getting a clear question seen by the most people, don't post a question when you can't check back at least a couple times in the next two hours after posting to address any clarifying questions.  Posting right before you go to bed is not a good practice.  I know that is a popular thing to do with some online forums - just come back the next day and see if you got any answers.  That isn't ideal for StackOverflow.  Unclear questions will often just get closed here.

Comment: Please don't take this as criticism, but as recommendations for the future from someone who has a lot of experience on SO.

Comment: FYI, in case you're curious, I removed my downvote (though there is still one other one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:-

```
$('*').mousedown(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 3) { //detect right click
        var background = $(this).css('background-image'); //get background image
        if(/url\(([^\)]+)\)/.test(background)){ // check background image exists
            var url = /url\(([^\)]+)\)/.exec(background)[1]; // get the url
            alert(url);     
        }
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p2hk0rjp/)

Comment: FYI, in IE the right click context menu comes up over this alert dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string from backgroundImage, you can pass an element to this method to get the url of the image in both cases:

```
 function getUrlFromElement(element){
    if(element.tagName.toLowerCase() === "img"){//check if it's an img
        return element.src; //it's an image, return src attribute
    }
    else{
        if(element.style.backgroundImage){//it's not an image, check if it has background Image
            return element.style.backgroundImage.slice(4,-1); //imageUrl starts at position 4 "url(" ends in length -1 to avoid closing ")"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check the `mousedown` event for mouse click.
- Switch the `event.button` to `case 2` for the right mouse button.
- Check the element's `style.backgroundImage` property
- Replace the `url()`
- Use a dummy input element to copy and select the style

Something along the lines of:

```
$('.efImage').on('mousedown', function (ev) {
    var dummy = $('#copytext'),
        style;

    switch (ev.button) {
        case 2:
            style = this.style.backgroundImage.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '');
            break;
    }

    if (style) {
        dummy.val(style).select();

        // selection to clipboard
        try {
            document.execCommand('copy');
        } catch (err) {
            $('textarea').val(dummy.val());
        }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/vp6pz5vg/)**

Answer (score -2):

Use getElementsByClass

```
var imgSrc = document.getElementsByClass("efImage").src;
```

Comment: This does not address the type of element in the OP's question.